# Shedlock creating multiple entries in database for single job

Tags: spring-boot

We are using shedlock for clustering on a azure webapp for containers. Now my clode looks something like:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/3 * * ?")
@SchedulerLock(name = "giveBonus", lockAtMostFor = TWO_HOURS, lockAtLeastFor = TWO_HOURS)
public void giveBonus() {
```

}

And my shedlock code looks like:

```
@Bean
public ScheduledLockConfiguration taskScheduler(LockProvider lockProvider) {
    return ScheduledLockConfigurationBuilder.withLockProvider(lockProvider).withPoolSize(10)
            .withDefaultLockAtMostFor(Duration.ofMinutes(10)).build();
}


@Bean
public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
}
```

Now, most of the time I see that even if we have one instance of the application, there are multiple entries in the database created with same job name and almost at the same time. Please see the snippet:

[image: database-snaphot]

What we are not able to figure out is that if this is correct behaviour or we are doing something wrong here.

The version of shedlock used by us is: 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have unique constraint on "name" column (primary key)

Comment: I added the unique constraint to name column and I can still see my job running twice. In fact, now, there is no entry getting created in the shedlock table too.

{
2018-10-29T08:38:00.000840575Z 2018-10-29 08:38:00.000  INFO 1 --- [TaskScheduler-5] c.n.s.p.a.s.FulfillPendingOrdersJob      : Fulfilling Pending Orders

2018-10-29T08:38:00.000863222Z 2018-10-29 08:38:00.000  INFO 1 --- [TaskScheduler-4] c.n.s.p.a.s.FulfillPendingOrdersJob      : Fulfilling Pending Orders
}

Comment: After restarting the pods, it works. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need database [constraints](https://github.com/yusufaytas/dlock/blob/master/dlock-jdbc/src/main/resources/ddls/postgres.ddl) to do so. You can certainly do that with [dlock](https://github.com/yusufaytas/dlock). Its implementation is database specific e.g. using database indexes to ensure there's one lock at a time.

Service A should be something like this.

```
@TryLock(name = "giveBonus", owner = "your-owner", lockFor = TWO_HOURS)
public void giveBonus() {
  //...
}
```

See [this post](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-mutual-exclusion) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation Will, but right now I am more interested in getting Shedlock solution to work. If it won't work at all, then I will give Dlock a try.